# Ftp saying `R:ICMP port unreachable` with special chars in file name when ftping to Windows

Tags: ftp

I am trying to transport a file from a Linux server to a Windows server using a cron job to kick off an ftp request. If the file is named `archive-2015-11-11-2.tar.gz` the ftp works great, however, when I copy this file under the name `archive-2015-11-12-00:00:01.tar.gz` and try to ftp from my Windows box I get the error `> R:ICMP port unreachable`. Is there a way I can transfer the file without renaming? I tried both `get` and `mget` but neither works.

Env

- OS: Windows
- Terminal: Cygwin

Comment: Your question is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: I disagree it is actually poor error handling in the ftp tool, which I believe, given that breakdown, is acceptable.

Comment: How does a poor error handling of the application make this a programming question? Though it not a poor error handling anyway. The comma has clearly probably a specific meaning in the tool (probably a port number separator).

Comment: I don't know why we have to have this convoy but the page says " but if your question generally covers…".. "software tools commonly used by programmers; " considering I was using this ftp application to programtically ftp a file using a cron job I think this question is valid. It isn't hardwareor networking  so it isn't serverfault. So I am confused

Comment: *"and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"* - Your problem is not unique to software development.

Comment: How do you figure? And what does that mean anyway I think you are being a little nit picky. Doesn't that mean any question about the file system in general is not valid? So no questions about Java file streaming or JSON because they are not unique to programming. Give it up your twisting the definitions provided.

Comment: Even better if the appropriate board isn't this one which one is it?

Comment: [su] is the right place.

Comment: And yes, any question about the file system in general is not valid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95066/discussion-between-jackie-and-martin-prikryl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colon is not a valid character in a Windows file spec.  The error message may be misleading but if you're trying to create a file named `archive-2015-11-12-00:00:01.tar.gz` on a Windows box that will not work.

Comment: The interesting this is the file was on a Linux server (where the filename is valid) and I was trying to transfer to Windows. However, it failed with a port error, but it must have been the filename in disguise